# Check if MacOS current sound output is optical or analog?

Tags: python, macos, shell, cocoa, applescript

Is there a way to get the **current active sound output connection in MacOS** from **Applescript**, maybe with a shell/cocoa/python command?
I saw some libraries to perform powerful scripts, but I just want to retrieve a value and I would prefer not to install libraries.
I also saw automatot script to open System Preferences, and then click tabs... But I don't like this kind of solution.

In other words, I would like to know if my active sound output is optical or analog, in order to properly modify output volume: if the ouput is analog, I can modify the output volume in the Finder, otherwise I have to modify it in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pure Applescript workaround, based on the fact that the output volume cannot be read with optical mini-jack:

```
on isOpticalSoundOutput() -- returns boolean
    local outputVolume
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            set outputVolume to the output volume of (get volume settings)
        end try
        return (outputVolume = missing value)
    end tell
end isOpticalSoundOutput
```

It works, though I have an Applescript "privilege violation -10004.

Comment: RE: "It works, though I have an Applescript "privilege violation -10004." --  The `get volume settings` _command_ is a part of **Standard Additions** and does not belong wrapped within a `tell application "Finder"` _block_ as **Finder** doesn't understand that _command_, and it may be why you are getting an error. Try it without wrapping it within a `tell application "Finder"` _block_.